# Maya users; how can I create my own particle emitter in Maya?

Tags: 3d, particles, maya, procedural

(Originally posted in the Programmers Stack Exchange, but was told to ask here instead. Whoops.)

Before you answer this with "well, use the built-in particle emitter", read further.

For one of my university assignments, I have to build a scene involving a Catherine wheel (a spinning firework, basically) attached to a fence post in Maya 2015. I had intended on using Maya's built-in particle emitter, but my lecturer has told me that he would prefer me to create my own.

I have only a vague idea of what to do. I know that I need to assign a position, velocity, lifespan and a trigger flag that re-spawns each particle (all of which are arrays that depend on the number of particles the user wishes to spawn), but I don't know how to arrange them.

Any tips and advice would be appreciated.

Thanks